# How to use React Context with useState hook to share state from different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am new to React and currently I'm working on a Gatsby site where I have a Layout.js(Parent) and Menu.js(Child), when the state changes on Menu, I'd like it passed to Layout.js.

What I am trying to do is when the menu is active, the text in the layout will change.

**Menu.js**

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from "react"
const MenuContext = createContext(1)

const Menu = (props) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(1)
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  }
  return(
    <div className={(active ? `open` : `close`)} onClick={clickHandler}></div>
  )
}

export { Menu, MenuContext }
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react"
import { Menu, MenuContext } from "../components/menu"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {

  const menuActive = useContext(MenuContext)

  return (
    <>
      <h1 style={{color:`#fff`}}>{(menuActive) ? `Menu Opened` : `Menu Closed`}</h1>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Menu />
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

It seems like `menuActive` is always printing 1. I can make sure the state is working fine inside Menu.js, but I don't know how to pass the state to Layout.js.

Any advices please, thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you just using props to pass data from the parent to child? Do you have a more complex situation where the state needs shared with more nested components?

Comment: Hi @James, I considered that method, but there will be more components that will be shared to the same state and I read it somewhere that using Context would be much cleaner way to do so if I have several nested components.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to have a Provider that wraps your App before you try to access the context values. In order to have a global and single provider, you need to export `wrapRootElement` instance from the gatsby-browser.js file. It would look like

MenuContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"

export const MenuContext = createContext()

export const MenuProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);
  return (
    <MenuContext.Provider value={{active,setActive}}>
      {children}
    </MenuContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

gatsby-browser.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MenuContext from './src/context/MenuContext';
const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
      <MenuProvider>
        {element}
      </MenuProvider>
  );
};
export { wrapRootElement }
```

Now you could use it within `Layout` like

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { Menu } from "../components/menu"
import { MenuContext } from '../menuContext';
const Layout = ({ children }) => {

  const {active} = useContext(MenuContext)

  return (
    <>
      <h1 style={{color:`#fff`}}>{(active) ? `Menu Opened` : `Menu Closed`}</h1>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Menu />
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

and within `Menu` you would have

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import  { MenuContext } from '../context/MenuContext';

const Menu = (props) => {
  const {active, setActive} = useContext(MenuContext)
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  }
  return(
    <div className={(active ? `open` : `close`)} onClick={clickHandler}></div>
  )
}

export { Menu }
```

Note: You need to create and export the context from a separate file to avoid any circular dependency

---

However, what you want to achieve can be done without the use of context provided you just to communicate between layout and Menu by lifting the state up to the Layout component

Menu.js

```
import React from "react"

const Menu = ({clickHandler, active}) => {
  return(
    <div className={(active ? `open` : `close`)} onClick={clickHandler}></div>
  )
}

export { Menu }
```

Layout.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import { Menu } from "../components/menu"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(1)
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1 style={{color:`#fff`}}>{(menuActive) ? `Menu Opened` : `Menu Closed`}</h1>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Menu clickHandler={clickHandler} active={active}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to resolve using Lift State Up method, however with more complicated components around that share the same state, I need to have a better understanding the use of Context API with your solution, but it seems I couldn't get it work. It keeps saying `setActive is not a function` after onClick is triggered.

Comment: Can you make sure that you have exported `wrapRootElement` from gatsby-browser.js and also passed the context value to provider as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Sorry took me a while, I double checked and now this is appearing ```Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. ```.

Comment: I was able to fix it by moving the`<Menu.Provider>` inside the context file and leave gatsby-browser.js file clean instead.

Comment: hi, i got error  *** setActive is not function***

Comment: MenuContext complains about `Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)`