# Downsides of putting state directly inside a React Context Provider?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I'm exporting a `LayoutContextProvider` component, so `App` can use it and fill it with the `value`:

```ts
// Shape of the layout context
const LayoutContext = 
  React.createContext<undefined | LayoutContextType>(undefined);

// Export the provider as a component
export const LayoutContextProvider = ({ 
  children, 
  value
}: ProviderProps<LayoutContextType>) => {
  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Export the hook to use the context
export const useLayoutContext = () => 
  React.useContext(LayoutContext) as LayoutContextType;
```

My context just expose some methods for controlling the state of global components, i.e:

```ts
interface LayoutContextType {
  settingsSiderbar: {
    isOpen: boolean, 
    open: () => void, 
    close: () => void,
  }
}
```

I am tempted to put the state inside the `LayoutContextProvider` and remove the `value` prop, like this way:

```ts
export const LayoutContextProvider = (
  children: ProviderProps<LayoutContextType>['children']
) => {
  const [isSettingsSidebarOpened, setSettingsSidebarOpened] = useState(false);

  const openSettingsSidebar = useCallback(() => {
    setSettingsSidebarOpened(true);
  }, []);
  const closeSettingsSidebar = useCallback(() => {
    setSettingsSidebarOpened(false);
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    settingsSiderbar: {
      isOpened: isSettingsSidebarOpened,
      open: openSettingsSidebar,
      close: closeSettingsSidebar,
    }
  }), [isSettingsSidebarOpened, openSettingsSidebar, closeSettingsSidebar]);

  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I've searched a bit abut I can't find any example of this practice. Is something that should be avoided? Any downsides?

Answer (score 0):

**Anecdotal evidence:** I use it in every project and works fine. It's sad that it's hard to find on google

You can even make it better by throwing an error here

```
export const useLayoutContext = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(LayoutContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('LayoutContext can be used only as a descendant of LayoutContextProvider');
  }
  return context;
}
```

This way you will get an error if you would try to use this context without the provider

Comment: Wow... so isn't a bad practice, isn't it.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144498/how-to-use-react-context-with-usestate-hook-to-share-state-from-different-compon :)